# MQLight Node.js clients stops receiving messages after idle time. AMQP/MQ Light on MQ 8.0.0.3

Tags: node.js, ibm-mq, amqp

I am having an issue with using the Node.js client with an IBM MQ 8.0.0.3 server.

My Node.js application receives messages just fine, but if I let the application idle for several hours (in this specific instance I had it idling, receiving no messages, for about 17 hours), and then publish a new message on the MQ server, nothing appears on the client side.

I have registered listeners for all events that the mqlight client can emit (except drain, the client is only a receiver), and none of them have been emitted during these 17 hours. Netstat on the client machine shows that I still have an established connection the the MQ server on port 5672.

If I restart the client application the messages appear instantly.

Is there some setting or piece of configuration I am missing? I need to able to rely on that if the application is running and connected, it will receive the messages, and I don't want to resort to periodically reconnecting the client as a workaround.

Relevant options used in my client:

```
clientOptions.service = 'amqp://mqserver';
clientOptions.id = 'nodejsclient';

subscribeOptions.autoConfirm = false;
subscribeOptions.qos = 1;
subscribeOptions.ttl = 24*60*60*1000; //24 hours TTL
```

Comment: Magnus, what version of the Node MQ Light client are you using? We had issues some time ago related to keep alives but I think they have been resolved for some time. Have you got an old version of the client? As Valerie says the AMQP beta for 8.0.0.3 has been superseded by the supported version in MQ 8.0.0.4. You could try upgrading to 8.0.0.4 to see if that resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You indicate you have MQ v 8.0.0.3 but you need MQ version 8.0.0.4 for MQ Light support.

Can you try 8.0.0.4 to see if that solves your problem? You will need to install the full version of MQ 8.0.0.4 from Passport Advantage rather than adding fixpack 4 to an existing MQ 8 installation.

Read more:  [MQ support for MQ Light and AMQP 1.0 released in 8.0.0.4](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/messaging/entry/MQ_support_for_MQ_Light_released_in_8_0_0_4?lang=en_uk)

Comment: This has not been reproducable on a 8.0.0.4 machine. I used 8.0.0.3 with the beta support, so I guess I can attribute this behaviour to the fact that it was a beta in 8.0.0.3 and seems to work better in 8.0.0.4. Case closed for the time being!